# Three.js Convert Customer ShaderMaterial to Lambert Material

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am currently using a cell shading script to shade a Lambert material on a model I am using.  I also have a custom Shader Material that I would also like to use the same script on but that is proving to be easier said than done.  I was wondering if there is a way to change the custom material in to a Lambert material.  I have done some looking and can't seem to find anything.  Any help would be much appreciated.  This is my code so far, the three_lamberton script is the one I am using and it applies to the object that I am applying an image to.  The scripts at the top are what I am using to layer images and set up the custom shader material.  Ignore the fact that some of the images are loaded in to the material more than once, I am only doing that as place holders currently.  I would like to be able to apply the three_lamberton script to the shader material named material_shh

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Web GL test 2</title>
</head>

<body style="overflow: hidden; background: black;">
    <div id="container">


</div>
    <script src="three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="OBJLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="three_lambertoon_c.js"></script>


    <script id="fragment_shh" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        #ifdef GL_ES
        precision highp float;
        #endif

        uniform sampler2D tOne;
        uniform sampler2D tSec;
        uniform sampler2D tThree;
        uniform sampler2D tFour;
        uniform sampler2D tFive;
        uniform sampler2D tSix;

    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main(void)
    {
        vec3 c;
        vec4 Ca = texture2D(tOne, vUv);
        vec4 Cb = texture2D(tSec, vUv);
        vec4 Cc = texture2D(tThree, vUv);
        vec4 Cd = texture2D(tFour, vUv);
        vec4 Ce = texture2D(tFive, vUv);
        vec4 Cf = texture2D(tSix, vUv);
        c = Ca.rgb * Ca.a + Cb.rgb * Cb.a + Cc.rgb * Cc.a + Cd.rgb * Cd.a 
            + Ce.rgb * Ce.a + Cf.rgb * Cf.a * (1.0 - Ca.a - Cb.a - Cc.a - Cd.a - Ce.a);
    gl_FragColor= vec4(c, 1.0);

    }

</script>

<script id="vertex_shh" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main()
    {
        vUv = uv;
        vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: How do you setup the material on your objects now? How exactly do want to convert what you have to something else? What did you try so far and where did you get stuck? You need to explain more clearly, with some small code samples, before this question is answerable.

Comment: updated, thanks for your interest in my question, let me know if there is anything else I can clarify

Comment: I attempted to recommend _small_ code samples! Looking through all that is quite daunting...

Comment: slimmed it down, this is how I am creating my customer shader material, and this is a link to the what I am trying to apply to it.  It is what I am applying to the lambert material I'm using http://www.neocomputer.org/projects/donut/

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I see what you are after, and I think you may be a little confused.

A material may only have one vertex shader, and one fragment shader at a time.  Three.js provides some default shaders, like `Lambert` that render things in lambert shading. That `labertoon.js` script appears to hack into the Three.js provided Lambert shader and permanently alter it, which means any Lambert material would use this hacked version instead.  This is an ugly way to do this.

See what the script does yourself, it's not long: http://www.neocomputer.org/projects/donut/three_lambertoon_c.js

The fact is combining shaders is tricky.  A shader has a single entry point `main()` and then a very specific sequence of operations.  The order of those operations is incredibly important, just as is the order of operations in a math problem.  So the solution is to write a new shader that does both things.

Pull the lines of shader code from that JS file, and then add them to your own custom shader.  Then stop using the `lambertoon` js file altogether.

In this case, though, you might be able to paste those lines from the toon shader directly into the bottom of your own fragment shader, and it might just work.

Comment: That is what I tried initially but kept coming up with the model not loading.  Tried several different setups and kept coming up empty so I was looking for a quick cheat work around.  Sounds like it will have to be the hard way.  Thanks for looking into it sir and for the info.

Comment: Your shader should never make your model "not load". That's like saying your paint is making your car not start. :) That said, if you shader has logical errors or fails to compile, the visualization of the model be incorrect or absent.  Keep an eye on the JS console for errors. If it can't compile a shader it'll tell you why.

Comment: Haha that means I was definitely doing something wrong.  Thanks for the tip.  Going to play around with it a bit later.  I'll let ya know.  Thanks again for the help.